# alias a dynamic sql table in Update statement

Tags: sql

I have tried this

```
SET @SQLUpdateTable = ' UPDATE '+@MTblName+ '  a
```

ad even this

```
SET @SQLUpdateTable = ' UPDATE '+@MTblName+ '  As a
```

Bu getting errors

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Please can someone help. ?

many thanks

Comment: just one more ' (single quote) you need to add at the end, and it will work (>‿◠)✌

Answer (score 0):

check this.

```
  SET @SQLUpdateTable = 'UPDATE'+@MTblName+'as a'
```

Comment: No this does not work... there are red lines under the aliases in the below code after this line     SET a.[Field1] = coalesce(t1.[Field1], a.[Field]),
     a.[Field2] = coalesce(t1.[Field2], a.[Field2]),

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @SQLUpdateTable = 'UPDATE T1 SET T1.FieldName = '+@value+ ' FROM ' +@MTblName+ ' T1 WHERE T1.ID' = +@Id+
```

Comment: Please explain why this line will solve the problem!